# We need better support for retina displays

Tags: feature-request, retina

The site looks a bit ugly now that I got used to the retina display. Here are few points that could/should make the site looks crispier :)

- Update the favicon to support the 32x32 version too
- The logos could be SVG and a fallback for IE3 to PNG or something, otherwise higher quality PNG for retina
- All the gravatar images should load the 2x image wherever they are appearing
- Use icon font for all the icons, [you know how it's done](http://blog.fogcreek.com/trello-uses-an-icon-font-and-so-can-you/)

The following image summarises pretty much everything:

[image: Stackoverflow on retina]

Comment: IE has never supported PNG favicons, not even IE 10 /pedant

Comment: @TimYiJiang no need for PNG favicons when the standard is the .ico, where you can have different sizes

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate.. but I think the other question has too many words.. this one just summarises the points :)