# Duplicate candidates: count is wrong, or scrolling is missing

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-suggestions

I recently voted to close [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216809/when-will-stack-overflow-support-retina-devices/) as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167244/we-need-better-support-for-retina-displays). When I first voted to close, I inadvertently clicked on a [different proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161373/hdpi-version-of-stack-exchange) (there were two proposed duplicates based on existing votes-to-close), which I didn't think was a better direct representation of this new question, then tried to get back to the two choices I was first offered. I wasn't able to do that. If I clicked back on the Closing > link at the top, then chose duplicate again, I was only offered the choice I originally clicked on.

So I cleared the URL, and typed "retina" - this is what I saw:

> [image: Image of the close dialog's duplicate panel with the word "retina" in the search bar. The panel mentions having 5 potential duplicate search results when only 4 are displayed]

Note that it says there are 5 results, but only 4 are shown (I suspect the one that is missing is the one that I wanted). If there are 5 results there and one is hidden from view, there is no way to scroll to see the 5th result.

What I should have done was closed the dialog entirely and/or refreshed the page. But this chain of events surprised me.

I really doubt this is browser-specific, but to pre-empt inevitable requests: Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: [No repro here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IyWjR.png), I see scroll bar just fine using Chrome 32 under Windows 7.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, but had you already clicked on the other potential duplicate? If you look closely at my screen shot, if that 5th item was there (and could be scrolled to), it should be marginally visible.

Comment: No repro with the steps provided, Chrome 32 on Windows 7. Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: @Stijn I can't on that question, because I've already voted to close. If you find me another question with two different VtC candidates but that hasn't been closed yet, I can try.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I picked a random question, it had more than two options before I typed something. Could be of significance indeed.

Comment: @Stijn what question?

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood the situation, I didn't test on a question with proposed duplicates from existing votes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231251/why-adding-an-element-of-correct-type-into-a-list-through-a-method-of-is-a), it has 2 different suggested duplicates, but be quick, 4 votes already.

Comment: @Stijn no, not quite, I got five results but I didn't find a clear and easy way to make sure I was typing criteria to include the proposed duplicate that I hadn't clicked.