# Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ image wacked

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-exchange-button

> [image]

And if I click on it...

> [image]

Looks like a CSS sprite issue...

I'm thinking that the image was recently changed, by looking at the name, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/share-sprite-new@2.png

Currently on `Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m`. Firefox is fine though, with all zoom levels.

Steps to reproduce:

Either browse the site on a device with Retina display, or using Chrome follow those steps:

1. Change zoom level to 150% or more.
2. Reload the page.

Comment: More information, please? Like, browser and OS version. No repro on FF 27.0.1, Win XP SP 3 though. Edited: even with any zoom level.

Comment: I see the same issue on OSx 10.9.2 Safari 7.0.2

Comment: I'm seeing this on both the mobile view and full site, Android 4.3, with Chrome, zoom is 100%

Comment: Same problem here, Chrome on OSX

Comment: Can confirm using `Chrome Version 33.0.1750.152` on OS X 10.9.2. Persists on all zoom levels, including 100%. Problem exists on Safari, but works fine on Firefox, same OS. (Seems to be a WebKit/Blink issue.)

Comment: "*browser zoom on 150%*" There's your problem.

Comment: @michaelb958: The browser zoom is not the issue.  I am reproducing on OSX Chrome 33.0.1750.152.

Comment: @sberry2A Looks like this is more serious than I thought. Ignore that zoom-level comment.

Comment: Just happened to me as well: Browser Google Chrome: `Version 33.0.1750.152` OS: `Ubuntu` Zoom level: 150%

Comment: It's okay on Chrome 33.0.1750.117 on Windows 7 for me, but b0rked on the default Android browser.

Comment: I can reproduce this on 33.0.1750.154 , Win 7 x64, but i have to do a page reload after i change the zooming level.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards have you tried a page reload after changing the zoom level

Comment: This bug also occurs on iOS 7.1 Safari.

Comment: @michaelb958 yesterday it looked fine even with Browserzoom 150%

Comment: No difference @Jehof, but then I appear to be a few builds behind everyone else. Maybe something dodgy did get pushed in webkit as has been suggested.

Comment: same problem on os x 10.9.2 with safari 7

Comment: Same problem with mobile theme on iOS on an iPhone 5

Comment: @Antony yes it is, that's how I was able to reproduce.

Comment: Same problem in Crome 33.0.1750.152 on OS X 10.8.5 on MacBook Pro with Retina display (without zoom)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I never use zoom and I can still see the problem. The fact that it occurs on different webkit browsers across multiple devices makes it very unlikely that zoom is the cause of the problem, though I suspect that the retina display has some effects similar to what zoom does on a normal display.

Comment: On my laptop now, Windows 7 with Chrome 33.0.1750.154m and I cannot repo the issue regardless of zoom level.  But I can still see it [on my phone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-image-wacked#comment738344_225821)

Comment: Same problem on Galaxy s3 android 4.3 standard webbrowser.

Comment: Same issue on the full version of the site with Safari on iOS 7.1 on an iPad 4.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Haven't we [talked about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209720/javascript-is-broken-on-meta#comment671682_209720)? (re http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/225821/revisions)

Comment: @balpha yep, but the impact is so big that the temptation was too big I guess. Hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, the fix is being built out right now.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A fix is rolling out now. A certain designer and a certain developer combined various sprites last night to reduce the http requests on first load...and they also conspired to screw up retina to see if we'd notice.

Hold strong my high-DPI brothers and sisters! We shall not tolerate this retina oppression!

Yours truly,
Nick Craver
Self-Appointed Leader, Stack Exchange Retinafication Revolution

<sub>P.S. Weekly meetings mocking standard DPI users are now 6pm Tuesday to Thursday due to the daylight savings change</sub>

Comment: That's good, even in your already high standards. Kudos!

Comment: Since it looks like you are our leader in the Retinafication Revolution.. when will our eyes going to stop bleeding every time we see the logo and other things on SO?! http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167244/142717

Comment: @Lipis soon, we just ordered Jin a rMBP so he can go retina crazy on all the sites. The <img> tags we haven't decided on yet (only a few), but everything referenced via LESS/CSS is relatively easy - just needs image work.

Comment: 2x the fun (or is it 4x) I can never remember how many dimensions count :/

Comment: @Nick for small images like little avatars, tags, etc.. you could serve only the high resolution image.. but then again you can evaluate what's best.. but since Jin is on it.. really looking forward :) Consider also SVG for the logos.. http://caniuse.com/svg

Comment: @Lipis we actually have a secret page in the works full of svg...we're definitely considering it, svg sprites and such

Comment: @Nick Super awesome.. in case you want some external clickers on this page.. ping somewhere..! SVG FTW!!!

Comment: @Lipis you'll see a mockup of the page this week I believe, if not then next...not ready yet as there's a lot of data work to make it live. I'm playing with SVG at night to illustrate the performance hit from SSL as well: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hAB6q.png ...this is gonna be a fun, interactive, blog post on SSL :)

Comment: Any status updates? I'm seeing some retina-compatible sprites, but site logos are still low-res (except this one!) — what's the rollout plan?

Answer (score 9):

I have quick fixed it in my Google Chrome Developer options like this and commented out the following:

```
.topbar .topbar-icon, .topbar .date-group-toggle, .topbar .icon-help>.triangle {
   background-image: url('../img/share-sprite-new@2.png?v=e119046ac45c');
   -moz-background-size: 300px 120px;
   -o-background-size: 300px 120px;
   -webkit-background-size: 300px 120px;
   background-size: 300px 120px;
```

Then looks fine on my Google Chrome even on 150%. 
I am posting this just in case it might be helpful for fixing it.

---

See images:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Changing `background-size` to `300px 240px` instead of commenting out all the rules solves me the problem on retina display. Besides of it, commenting out `background-image` makes image blurred because of fallback to sprite not adapted to retina displays.