# Fonts while viewing Stack Overflow appear strange in Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: support, user-interface, fonts, font-size

The fonts looked great until this morning, when the font lost its bold style as you can see in the pictures.

It used to be bold and now it is tiny, and plus, all code blocks in the pages looks smaller, and I don't know why.

I captured the first image which has bold font as it is a web page that was opened yesterday: if I refresh the page, it would look like the second image.

Should be like this.

[image: The old style]

Now looks like this.

[image: The new style]

Comment: now that the fonts aren't bold anymore, they look too small. please make them a tad larger!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be due to a Stack Overflow redesign that has not been officially announced on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) yet, despite having been rolled out.

It seems to be similar to the [Meta Stack Overflow redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update) that was rolled out about two months ago, and the reason why your fonts are smaller is likely due to your use of a higher resolution display, which this redesign now properly supports as part of the "[Retinafication Revolution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225821/stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-image-wacked/225859#225859)."

Comment: I have been using this 27 inch monitor with 2560x1440 resolution for a while, it may take me sometime to get used to the new flat style.